# Sought: Term for nominal use of adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives

If this turns out to be duplicative, I apologize.

Is there a concise term for the use of an adjective -- without a noun -- AS a noun?

For example, instead of
"Rich people often eat lobster stuffed with Himalayan hummingbird tongue."
substitute
"The rich often eat lobster stuffed with Himalayan hummingbird tongue."

Comment: @Thomas François \\ Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: _The rich_ is understood as _rich people_. The word "rich" is called a **'fused-head noun phrase'**, where the fusion is between the head of the NP, "people", and the modifier "rich".

Comment: There are constraints on its use. Whereas, for instance, in most European languages saying something like "the/a (singular masculine) old" means "the/an old man", English does not allow any kind of adjective to stand for a singular noun; only classes of people (not usually objects) that are defined by the adjectives. So you can talk about _the rich_ or the _stupid_, but you have to say _the big ones_ or _the blue ones_ if you mean all the things in a collection that are big or blue. It's a very limited construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **antonomasia**.

[odo](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/antonomasia)

> the substitution of an epithet or title for something (usually a proer name)